# how to get current system date in validation.xml in struts2

Tags: struts2

i want to compare the date field with the current date.
for that i need current date into the validation.xml file
so that i can compare it
how can i implement it
i m using struts2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get something working with the [expression validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html).  It lets you specify an OGNL expression.  Combined with OGNL's ability to call [static methods](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/html/LanguageGuide/staticMethods.html), you might be able to hack something together like:

myDate < @java.util.Calendar@getInstance().time

I'm not sure this would actually work though, as I've never tried it.